# In Athena how do I query a member of a struct in an array in a struct?

Tags: sql, json, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to figure out how to query where I am checking the value of `usage` given the following table creation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.test (
     `id` string,
     `foo` struct< usages:array< struct< usage:string,
     method_id:int,
     start_at:string,
     end_at:string,
     location:array<string> >>> 
) PARTITIONED BY (
         timestamp date 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         'serialization.format' = '1' ) LOCATION 's3://foo.bar/' TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I would like to have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test" WHERE foo.usages.usage is null;
```

When I do that I get:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:53: Expression "foo"."usages" is not of type ROW

If I make my query where I directly index the array as seen in the following it works.

```
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test" WHERE foo.usages[1].usage is null;
```

My overall goal though is to query across all items in the `usages` array and find any row where at least one item in the `usages` array has a member `usage` that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by unnesting the array into rows and then check those for `null` values. This will result in one row per `null`-value entry.

```
select * from test
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(foo.usages) AS t(i)
where i.usage is null
```

So if you only need the unique set, you must run this through a `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct id from test
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(foo.usages) AS t(i)
where i.usage is null
```

Comment: My intuition suggests UNNEST+DISTINCT is not going to be the most performant option. Even once Athena gets the UNNEST optimization (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/901), DISTINCT may still be costly for a bigger data set.

Answer (score 8):

Athena is based on Presto. In Presto 318 you can use [`any_match`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match):

```
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test"
WHERE any_match(foo.usages, element -> element.usage IS NULL);
```

I think the function is not available in Athena yet, but you can emulate it using [`reduce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce).

```
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test"
WHERE reduce(
  foo.usages, -- array to reducing
  false, -- initial state
  (state, element) -> state OR element.usage IS NULL, -- combining function
  state -> state); -- output function (identity in this case)
```

Comment: it is true that `any_match` is not available in Athena

Comment: this reduce needed a small change in order to work for me... I had to replace `||` with `OR` keyword (else it treated that as array concatenation operator)

Comment: @Anentropic right!.. Too much Java everyday. Updated, thanks.

Comment: `any_match` is still not available yet. For a list of all available Presto functions in Athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Another way to emulate `any_match(<array>, <function>)` is with `cardinality(filter(<array>, <function>)) > 0`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test"
WHERE any_match(foo.usages, element -> element.usage IS NULL);
```

Becomes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "foo"."test"
WHERE cardinality(filter(foo.usages, element -> element.usage IS NULL)) > 0
```

Comment: If you have an array of key/value pairs, you can nest another filter to filter for the key and then value.
`SELECT * FROM "foo"."test" WHERE cardinality(filter(filter(key_values, kv -> kv.key = 'my-key'), kv -> kv.value = 'my-value')) > 0`